# Are the electrons in the Delft University experiment really entangled?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I have been studying the Loophole-free Bell test at the Delft University.
They were using the "Entanglement By Accident" method.
When they trigger an electron, the electron falls back in one of two possible states, emitting a photon in a corresponding polarisation. 
This is what they did (as far as I know).

- They were firing both electrons 10.000 times per seconds.
- The photons scatter around, but about 4 times per hour the photons at both end
  ended up in the fiber cables.
- The detector in the center detects about 1 out of 4 times that the photons have different polarisations, without knowing which photon has what polarisation.
- This means that the electrons must have different states.
- Now they measure the state of each electron at exactly the same moment.
- And in 80% of the 245 times they indeed see a different state.

But why are professors so excited about that?
For me it's quite clear that the electrons **should have** different states because they selected only the photon-pairs with different polarisation.
What am I missing?

Comment: "The" Delft University experiment? There's only been a single experiment performed at Delft University *ever*? (Or, in other words: you are in an academic forum, and you are expected to provide suitable references that uniquely identify what it is you're talking about.)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is quantum entanglement considered to be an active link between particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/why-is-quantum-entanglement-considered-to-be-an-active-link-between-particles)