# Writing matrix of a second quantization Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, second-quantization

I am studying second quantization for first time. Let we have a a Hamiltonian (corresponding to a chain of particles with nearest neighbor hopping 't', ignore spin, on-site potential and interaction potential between two particles) that is given in first quantization as:
$$H_{1st}=t\sum_{m=1}^N|m><m+1|+h.c.$$
$$H_{1st}=t(|1><2|+|2><3|+|3><4|+|4><1|+h.c.)$$
It can be written in matrix form as following (N=4 and with periodic boundary condition):
$$H_{1st}=t(|1><2|+|2><3|+|3><4|+|4><1|+h.c.)$$
using
$$|1>=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}; 
  |2>=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}...$$ and so on... we can write our matrix as:
$$H_{1st}=t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
In second quantization this Hamiltonian can be written as:
$$H_{2nd}=t\sum_{m=1}^Nc_m^\dagger c_{m+1}+h.c.$$
that can be written as for N=4
$$H_{2nd}=t(c_1^\dagger c_{2}+c_2^\dagger c_{3}+c_3^\dagger c_{4}+c_4^\dagger c_{1}+h.c.)$$

How do we write matrix from this last equation of $H_{2nd}?$

Comment: Given a linear transformation $T$, the matrix element $T_{ij}$ means that you start with basis vector $\left \lvert j \right \rangle$, act transformation $T$, and then ask what is the component along basis element $\left \lvert i \right \rangle$ of the result. In other words, $T_{ij} \equiv \langle i | T | j \rangle$. So really you just need to think about what your basis vectors are in 2nd quantization.

Comment: in first quantization our basis can be $|m>$ states as I used. Can you tell me how can I choose basis in 2nd quantization for this example?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you already are using second quatization. Take a look at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122570/which-is-more-fundamental-fields-or-particles).

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If you liked the answer to that post on second quantization, you can vote up. If something is not clear, you can leave a comment asking for more information.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to give a Up vote right now. That answer was really very very helpful. I will give a up vote to that answer right after getting enough reputation points for up-vote.

Comment: I see that you have a tiny misunderstanding on the Dirac bra-ket formalism. In order to have a solid understanding of kets, their representation, operators and their representation in quantum mechanics I suggest you read the first chapter of Sakurai and solve the exercises.  You will have much less difficulty dealing with QM at the rest of your life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking single particle as basis we can write our basis set as: (for N=4) 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000.

Matrix $H_{2nd}$ becomes
$$H_2=\begin{bmatrix}<0001|H|0001>&<0001|H|0010>& ...& <0001|H|1000>\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\<1000|H|0001>&<1000|H|0010>&.&<1000|H|1000>\end{bmatrix}$$
$$H_2=t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So as you can see, you were already using second quantization!