# what does antisymmetrizing mean when it comes to electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, many-body, identical-particles

Consider two electron at $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ respectively. Is it possible to anti-symmetrize the total state of the the system just with the above information? If I make
$$|\psi\rangle = [|x\rangle|y\rangle-|y\rangle|x\rangle]\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
is it not zero as tensor product vectors $|x\rangle|y\rangle $and $|y\rangle|x\rangle$ are the same? Can someone explain when one needs to do antisymmetrization for electron wave functions and with respect what?

Comment: There are two questions here: 1) Are $|x\rangle|y\rangle$ and $|y\rangle|x\rangle$ the same, and 2) When do we need to use antisymmetrization? Please ask just one question per post, as this makes it easier for others to write an answer.

Comment: You may find [this post about particles and fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122570/which-is-more-fundamental-fields-or-particles) helpful.