# Why can't two different quantum states evolve into the same final state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, time-evolution, unitarity

Is it true that two different states cannot evolve into the same final state? Can they achieve this state at different times? If yes, what is the proof?

Comment: I feel you just need to add that your question assumes that dissipation on any kind isn't allowed.

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?

Answer (score 21):

> Is it true that two different states cannot evolve into the same final state?

That depends on exactly what you mean.
If we consider the total state of a closed system, then two different states will never simultaneously evolve into the same state at any later time.
You may have learned that quantum states evolve with a unitary transformation, i.e.
$$ \lvert \Psi(t) \rangle = U(t) \lvert \Psi(0) \rangle$$
where $U(t)$ is unitary, which means that $U(t)^\dagger = U(t)^{-1}$.
That being the case,
\begin{align}
\langle \Phi(t)|\Psi(t) \rangle 
&= \langle U(t) \Phi(0) | U(t) \Psi(0) \rangle \\
\text{(definition of Heritian conjugate)} \quad &= \langle \Phi(0) | U(t)^\dagger U(t) | \Psi (0) \rangle \\
\text{(unitarity)} \quad &= \langle \Phi(0) | U(t)^{-1} U(t) | \Psi (0) \rangle \\
&= \langle \Phi(0) | \Psi (0) \rangle \, .
\end{align}
So you can see, the inner product between two states does not change as time evolves.
Two states that are the same have inner product of 1, but states that are not the same have inner product not 1.
Therefore, two states that are not initially the same cannot become the same later under unitary evolution.

On the other hand, if we allow measurement, it is possible for two initially different states to wind up being the same.
For example, if we have a two level system starting in state $(\lvert 0 \rangle + e^{i \phi} \lvert 1 \rangle)/\sqrt 2$ for any value of $\phi$, it could collapse to $\lvert 0 \rangle$ after a measurement.
Note, however, that in this case there is randomness, i.e. we cannot make a situation where two intitially different states deterministically evolve to the same final state.
If you *could* do that, I'm pretty sure you could control the future, communicate faster than light, and destroy the entire universe.

> Can they achieve this state at different times?

Yeah, sure.
Consider a two level system with Hamiltonian
$$ H = \hbar \frac{\omega}{2} \sigma_x \, .$$
The propagator for this system is
$$U(t) = \cos(\omega t / 2) \mathbb{I} - i \sin(\omega t / 2) \sigma_x =
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \cos(\omega t / 2) && -i \sin(\omega t / 2) \\
  -i \sin(\omega t / 2) && \cos(\omega t / 2)
  \end{array}
\right)$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ means the identity.
If we start with state $\lvert 0 \rangle$, then the state at time $t$ is
$$
U(t) \lvert 0 \rangle = \cos(\omega t / 2) \lvert 0 \rangle - i \sin(\omega t / 2) \lvert 1 \rangle
$$
Similarly, if we had started with $i \lvert 1 \rangle$, we'd get
$$U(t) i \lvert 1 \rangle = \sin(\omega t / 2) \lvert 0 \rangle + i \cos(\omega t / 2) \lvert 1 \rangle \, .
$$
Now look at two particular times:
$$U(t = \pi / 2 \omega) \lvert 0 \rangle
= \cos(\pi / 4) \lvert 0 \rangle - i \sin(\pi / 4) \lvert 1 \rangle
= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\lvert 0 \rangle - i \lvert 1 \rangle)$$
and
$$U(t = 3 \pi / 2 \omega) i \lvert 1 \rangle
= \sin(3\pi/4)\lvert 0 \rangle  + i \cos(3 \pi / 4) \lvert 1 \rangle
= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\lvert 0 \rangle - i \lvert 1 \rangle) \, .$$
So we can see that two initially different states evolve to the same state, but at different times.

Comment: I think there is a simpler way to argue that two different states cannot simultaneously evolve into the same state: Time evolution by some time $t$ is given by a unitary operator $U(t)$, unitary implies invertible, implies injective. Hence $U(t)\Psi = U(t)\Phi$ implies $\Psi = \Phi$.

Comment: @Peter Yep, that's a good argument. Why not edit it in?

Comment: What about something like a Bose-Einstein condensate?

Comment: @N.Steinle What about it would you like to know?

Comment: Are BEC's not covered by your proof? Since BEC's are quantum (statistical) systems where the majority of bosons evolve to the same ground state even though they very well could have started from initially different states. I'm not arguing against your answer, I'm just curious about its limitations.

Comment: @N.Steinle a system of bosons that is cooling down below $T_c$ by definition has heat being taken out of it, and therefore is not a closed system with unitary evolution. If you kept track of whatever was absorbing this heat you would in principle find a unitary evolution of the schematic form |not-BEC$\rangle$ |colder environment$\rangle \rightarrow$ |BEC$\rangle$ |warmer environment $\rangle$

Comment: @Rococo Just because the temperature is changing via heat does not make the system open. It can be a closed system even with an exchange of energy with an environment - it's not an isolated system though. An isolated system is what you've called "closed" whereby no energy is exchanged with the environment (thru heat nor work). Do you all mean that the system has to be isolated, rather than closed, for this?

Comment: @N.Steinle I'm not sure this terminology is always used consistently, but yes, the system must be isolated from energy exchange for unitary evolution. More generally, there must not be any interactions with external degrees of freedom that could carry away any information about the state of the system. So it is a pretty strong requirement.

Comment: @N.Steinle I think you're confusing "multiple particles being in the same state" with "an entire quantum system being in the same state". These two things are not the same, and only sound the same because of an unfortunate abuse of language. Take a look at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122570/) and my answer to it.

Comment: @DanielSank While he might be making this mistake, even so it is true that a thermalization process is necessarily a many-to-one mapping, at least for a local observable, so it is a good question indeed to ask how this plays nicely with unitarity. And that fact that for BEC you end up with a nearly pure state sharpens the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ be two states that evolve into the same state after some time $t$. Time evolution after time $t$ is given by a unitary operator $U(t)$. In particular, this means that $U(t)$ is invertible, so we have $U(t)^{-1}U(t) = 1$. Now we have by assumption that $U(t)\Psi = U(t)\Phi$. Multiplying both sides of this equation by $U(t)^{-1}$ from the left we obtain $\Psi = \Phi$. So if two states evolve into the same state after some time $t$, they were the same to begin with.

Time evolution furthermore has the property that $U(t)U(s) = U(t+s)$. Let $t\neq 0$. Now suppose that we have some state $\Phi$ with the property that $U(s)\Phi \neq \Phi$. Set $\Psi = U(s)\Phi$. We then get
\begin{equation}
 U(t)\Psi = U(t)(U(s)\Phi) = U(t+s)\Phi.
\end{equation}
We then have that the states $\Psi$ and $\Phi$, (which are different), evolve into the same state $U(t+s)\Phi$, but after different times.

In fact, this is the *only* way this can happen. That is, if there are two different states $\Phi \neq \Psi$ such that $U(t)\Phi = U(t')\Psi$, then there exists a time $s$ such that $\Psi = U(s) \Phi$. Maybe finding a proof for this claim is a good exercise.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\ket#1{|#1\rangle}$
More simply. As to first question: let $\ket{a,0}$ be a state vector
taken at time 0, $\ket{a,t}$ the same state evolved at time $t$.

*Note* 1: Schrödinger picture is used, where states evolve in time, observables don't.

*Note* 2: I'm using a rather different ket notation. I don't write things like $\ket{\Psi(t)}$ because I think this is a misinterpretation of Dirac's notation.

We have 
$$\ket{a,t} = U(t)\,\ket{a,0}$$ 
where $U(t)$ is unitary. Assume now that another $\ket{b,0}$ exists, such that also 
$$\ket{a,t} = U(t)\,\ket{b,0}.$$
Then
$$\ket{b,0} = U^{-1}(t)\,\ket{a,t} = U^{-1}(t)\,U(t)\,\ket{a,0} = \ket{a,0}.$$

Now for the second question. You're asking if
$$\ket{a,t} = \ket{b,t'} \tag1$$
could happen, for $t'\ne t$. Let's expand eq. (1), using $U$:
$$U(t)\,\ket{a,0} = U(t')\,\ket{b,0}$$
$$\ket{b,0} = U^{-1}(t')\,U(t)\,\ket{a,0} = U(-t')\,U(t)\,\ket{a,0} = 
U(t-t')\,\ket{a,0}.$$
This is the condition $\ket{a,0}$ and $\ket{b,0}$ are to obey, in order that $\ket{a,t}$ and $\ket{b,t'}$ be equal.

Answer (score 3):

Excluding wave function collapse, wave functions evolve deterministically, and this determinism goes both ways in time. So if you take  $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ such that there is some $t_0$ for which $\Psi(t_0)=\Phi(t_0)$, then as long as they evolve under the same transformation, you have  $\Psi(t)=\Phi(t)$ for all $t$. Thus, you can have neither two wavefunctions that are the same at one time evolve into different wavefunctions at a different time, nor two wavefunctions that are different at one time evolve into the same wavefunction at another time.

A state can evolve into what another state was at another time, i.e. $\Psi(t_1)=\Phi(t_2)$. But if they evolve under a time-constant transformation, then if we define $\Delta t= t_2-t_1$, then $\Psi(t)=\Phi(t+\Delta t)$ for all $t$; the two states are simply time-shifted version of each other.

Comment: The first 4 words could be removed; "wave function collapse" is not part of QM, just some magical thinking to smear away the difference between how QM describes nature and how many humans expect it to be.

Comment: @R.. not necessarily, this statement is highly opinion-based.

Comment: @Helen: My statement? There is absolutely no such thing *within the theory*, and provably no hidden variables that make it possible to introduce such a thing within the theory. It's non-falsifiable, and thereby a matter of some people's "religion" around QM, not part of QM itself.

Comment: If something has been used for decades and during the last year some people say it never has, then it is highly opinion-based until it turns out to be correct. Clarification: I'm not saying that you are necessarily wrong; but answering that collapse is not part of QM without stating that this is an opinion for the time being, does not lead to objective answers.

Comment: @Helen: *Belief* in "wave function collapse" is pretty widespread, but I don't think the statement that QM has nothing to say about it (and can't) is at all contoversial among the scientific community.