# In what way is a wave-only description of quantum mechanics insufficient?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wave-particle-duality

Edit: **What can be explained by wave-particle duality that cannot be explained by waves?**

My understanding of the Standard Model is that what we observe as a particle is really a quantized wave packet, and that all particle phenomenon can be described in that way. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/535742/26466) answer states that quantum fields are both wave-like and particle-like.

For example, at low intensities, light is detected as single particles. Can that not be explained by the wave interacting with the detector in such a way that the wave collapses to a point, which is necessarily quantized? In what way is the Standard Model not describable purely as waves in quantum fields?

Someone cited particle tracks through a bubble chamber as a reason why wave-only is insufficient. Can this not be described as quantized wave packets?

Comment: The question seems to be based on a presumed distinction between "particle" and "quantized wave packet." What is the distinction you have in mind? (The words that I put in quotation-marks are all overloaded in physics, so the intended meaning is not at all obvious from the words themselves.)

Comment: When I read posts on SE or Wikipedia, it seems that the consensus is that electrons etc cannot be described purely as wave phenomenon. I may be conflating terms, but I think of 'particles' as solitons - a strongly localized self-reinforcing wave. And I thought particle behavior could be described purely in terms of quantized solitons in quantum fields. And that seems like a really straight forward way to explain superposition and all that. But people keep on saying, "No, it's really this mysterious wave-particle duality and photons are really particles **and** waves."

Comment: "No, it's really that this mysterious wave-particle duality means that  photons have the properties of both  particles and waves." is exactly right. It's meaningless to ask what is "really" going on as John Bell showed us thatt there is no (local) "reality."

Comment: @mikestone In the context of Bell's theorem, 'realism' refers to the notion that there is some underlying hidden variable that explains the probabilistic behavior of quantum mechanics. It has *nothing* to do with ontology. In so much as the theorem is correct, in no way does it show that 'there is no (local) "reality"' in any ontological sense. It just asserts that local hidden variables theories are incorrect.

Comment: I would say it’s insufficient because you can’t explain what a light wave is other than billions of photons particles. You should ask the same question about particles.

Comment: [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 frequency is the difference between red and blue photon.

Comment: "explain what a light wave is other than billions of photons particles." I don't follow. What explanatory power does "billions of particles" have that "photon wave" or even "billions of wave packets" does not?

Comment: @EthanReesor We’ve only description is insufficient because you cannot explain what a light wave is. A particle can be described. You don’t have to know everything about the particle for instance you don’t know what protons and neutrons exactly but they are particles. Photons are particles and are more sufficient than waves.

Comment: A particle can be physically described in many ways. A wave packet cannot be physically described in anyway.

Comment: @ Ethan Reesor.  I have no idea what "ontology" means (the study of "things" perhaps?) but the surely usual account of Bell after Bernard d'Espagnat" is "no local reality"?  Anywa,y I intended to be provaocative  to start a debate about QM.  Maybe I succeeded? :)

Comment: @mikestone Ontology is the study of the nature of being. "The world is a simulation" and "Physics describes the true underlying nature of reality" are both ontological assertions in that they assert something about the nature of being. Beyond asserting that a local hidden variable theory cannot be consistent with observed phenomenon, Bell's theorem makes no assertions about the nature of being. That is, it makes no statements about what does or does not 'really exist' beyond ruling out local hidden variable theories.

Comment: @mikestone John Bell had a limited view of what a particle could be or do. He never even considered oscillating or linear aspects of a photon. He only considered polarization.

Comment: @Bill Alsept: John Bell was a very experienced particle physicist. He co-discovered the Adler-Bell-Jackiw axial anomaly and its relation to the $\pi_0\to \gamma+\gamma$ decay. He knew full well how field theory worked and all properties of photons.

Comment: @mikestone He still only considered polarization.

Answer (score 1):

"No, it's really that this mysterious wave-particle duality means that  photons have the properties of both  particles and waves." is exactly right. It's meaningless to ask what is "really" going on as John Bell showed us that there is no (local) "reality."

As    Mermin [says](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9801057.pdf): there are only *correlations* (between measurements) but there are no *correlates* (things that are correlated).

A persistent belief that there is some "reality" is the biggest block to understanding quantum mechanics.

Comment: I am asking specifically, in what way is a wave-only explanation insufficient? I have zero interest in metaphysics or what "reality" is. I am asking, why can't it be explained as waves? You do not answer my question.

Comment: @Ethan Reesor:  Because waves do not produce individual spots of light  on a screen.

Comment: I've only scratched the surface of quantum mechanics, but I fail to see why a soliton wave in the photon field cannot explain individual spots of light, or why that behavior could not be explained by QM interactions forcing the wave to localize to a soliton upon detection.

Comment: @Ethan Reeson. The QM wave Schroedinger equation  is *linear.*  There can be no solitons in Schroedinger waves.  The  waves with solitons result from  quantizing *non-linear* theories whose waves interact, and whose waves are *not* the waves of the Schroedinger equation.

Comment: "The soliton model applied to the electrons can be extended to the electromagnetic field providing an unambiguous description for the photon." https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00110