# Elementary particle detection post-collision

Tags: particle-physics, elementary-particles, large-hadron-collider

**How do you detect elementary particles?** What do you aim your detector at? What's a detector physically? How do you know that a particle "happened", if (I assume) you can't see it? Is the process somehow indirect?

Videos about LHC talk a lot about pre-collision, but in little detail about what happens after.

I'm not a physicist, so simple explanation would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: Maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273032/what-exactly-is-a-photon/273180#273180  , also this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535739/can-elementary-particles-be-explained-adequately-by-a-wave-only-model/535755#535755

Comment: Have you heard of the [Geiger counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter)? This is one of the simplest particle detectors. Of course, those at the LHC are much more sophisticated, but the key principle is similar: measuring the energy deposit by the particle in a certain medium.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_detector).