# Isn't the disturbance in quantum field an interpretation of quantum wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-interpretations

In quantum mechanics, a particle is neither a wave nor a particle but is described by a wave function which does not have a physical interpretation. But in quantum field theory, a particle is a disturbance in the associated field. Isn't the disturbance in quantum field an interpretation of quantum wave function?

Answer (score 2):

> In quantum mechanics, **a** particle is neither a wave nor a particle but is described by a wave function which does not have a physical interpretation

Note the bold **a** particle. The quantum mechanical equations , Dirac, Klein Gordon, quantized Maxwell, all describe a single particle.

The postulates of Quantum Field Theory are the postulates of Quantum mechanics, exactly. QFT was invented as a mathematical tool for the study of many particle systems in quantum mechanics, that allows for calculating crossections of interactions and decay probabilities.

> Isn't the disturbance in quantum field an interpretation of quantum wave function?

If you mean by interpretation a different mathematical formulation of the wave function for interacting particles, the answer is yes.

Note that the fields on which the creation and annihilation operators work are the *plane wave wavefunction*s, (for example [see here](http://polywww.in2p3.fr/%7Epaganini/ch2.pdf)) i.e. the solution of the corresponding quantum mechanical equations for single particles. As a probability the $Ψ^*Ψ$ of a plane wave cannot describe the location of a particle as measured in the lab. For single tracks of particles the [wavepacket solution h](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html)as to be used .

For calculating crossections and decays, the Feynman diagrams using QFT are accurate  and validated by experiments.

See also my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122570/what-is-more-fundamental-fields-or-particles/122573#122573) .